# Simple Imputation model n_feature and input n_feature not matching

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, kaggle

I am trying to learn Simple Imputer on the data set provided on the course tab on Kaggle - https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/missing-values

CSV file is available on above link.

While trying out the code I am getting following error.

```
ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 6 and input n_features is 9
```

Any help to sort out the issue will be appreciated.

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.read_csv('/Users/ratnam03chanakya/Desktop/Projects/Kaggle/02.melb_data/melb_data.csv')

df0.head()

y = df0.Price

features = ['Rooms', 'Distance', 'Bathroom', 'Car', 'Landsize', 'BuildingArea','YearBuilt', 'Lattitude', 'Longtitude']

X = df0[features]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X,y,random_state=0)

# Get names of columns with missing values

cols_with_missing = [col for col in X_train.columns if X_train[col].isnull().any()]

# Drop columns in training and validation data model_selection

reduced_X_train = X_train.drop(cols_with_missing, axis=1)

reduced_X_valid = X_valid.drop(cols_with_missing, axis=1)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

def score_dataset(X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid):
    model0 = RandomForestRegressor()
    model0.fit(reduced_X_train, y_train)
    model0_predict = model0.predict(X_valid)
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_valid,model0_predict)
    return mae

print("MAE from Approach 1 (Drop columns with missing values):")
print(score_dataset(reduced_X_train, reduced_X_valid, y_train, y_valid))



# IMPUTATION
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

my_imputer = SimpleImputer()

imputed_X_train = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.fit_transform(X_train))

imputed_X_valid = pd.DataFrame(my_imputer.transform(X_valid))

# Imputation removed column names; put them back

imputed_X_train.columns = X_train.columns

imputed_X_valid.columns = X_valid.columns

print("MAE from Approach 2 (Imputation):")
print(score_dataset(imputed_X_train,imputed_X_valid,y_train,y_valid))
```

Comment: *Where exactly* does the error pop up? Please update your post to include the full error trace.

Comment: @desertnaut The error occurs at the last line --- print(score_dataset(imputed_X_train,imputed_X_valid,y_train,y_valid)) as well within defining get_mae in the line --- model0_predict = model0.predict(X_valid).